# Serenity BDD: Use JBehave steps in dependency for local stories

Tags: java, jbehave, serenity-bdd

In Serenity BDD, is there a way to import steps from dependencies for use in local stories?  I'm pulling in other libraries (that also use Serenity) from other teams and want to be able to use one of their steps in my own story.  I can find a way to import and run their stories, but not just drag in their steps for my own use.

I'm using Java as the base language.

Comment: I try this and have problems. Steps from other projects are ignored- they are PENDING. Did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that Serenity will pick up on steps brought in through dependencies all on its own, so no need for anything fancy.